# What are the dangers of cutting PCB with Dremel?

Tags: pcb, protection

I'm cutting PCB's with a Dremel. Works really fine at high speed and with the finest cutting wheel. Can get really nice and clean results.

There's a lot of project and dust so I place next to my third hand a large PC fan at maximum speed oriented to the opposite of me, wear protection glasses for projection and a 3M dust mask for dusts.

But after the cutting there's still a freaking smell in the room and some dust floating in the air.

Are these dangerous? Should I quit and ventilate the room for 15 minutes before continuing to work? I don't know the composition of PCB and I'm asthmatic so...

Comment: I'll let someone else answer on the toxicity of the material (or lack thereof) but you really should try to make sure there isn't a lot of particulate floating around in your workspace, regardless of the material. The mask/glasses are a good idea but you probably want an actual fan or blower if your work area is collecting dust like that.

Comment: You would probably be better served by using a vacuum to collect the dust rather than a fan to blow it around the room even more. PCBs usually contain fiberglass, so the dust from grinding/cutting it will contain tiny glass particles. Not something I want to breathe.

Comment: Can you run water over the PCB while cutting?  This will lubricate the cutter and reduce dust.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a [MSDS datasheet for FR-4 material](http://www.pcbsupplies.compile-it.com/health/fr4.pdf), which is commonly used in PCBs.

Highlights:

> Machining, grinding or sawing this material may generate harmful dusts. Continuous filament glass fiber is not
>   considered flbrogenic; however, it Is woven from E-Glass fibers which are listed by IARC as "special purpose glass
>   fibers" and designated as "possibility of carcinogenic in human.” Inhalation of copper fumes, while not expected to
>   occur under typical conditions of use, may cause metal fume fever. See Section 8 for exposure controls.

The cited section 8 says:

> ENGINEERING CONTROLS:
>   Use local exhaust when machining, grinding or sanding to minimize exposures and maintain airborne dust and fiber
>   concentrations below occupational exposure limits.
>
> PERSONAL PROTECTIVE EQUIPMENT:
>   RESPIRATORY PROTECTION: In the absence of adequate general or local ventilation, use a NIOSH-or local
>   authority-approved respirator with at least an N95 filter if exposure limits are exceeded.
>
> SKIN PROTECTION: Wear
>   gloves during prolonged contact to avoid skin Irritation from dust.
>
> EYE PROTECTION: Use safety glasses or a face
>   shield when machining, grinding or sawing this material.

So, by using a mask and fan, you've likely kept yourself reasonably safe. You might want to consider getting an electronics-grade vacuum cleaner that meets N95 to collect and contain dust that otherwise may escape into the air.

Comment: Just to add to the above answer, if you are building a vacuum rather than using a respirator, a HEPA-rated filter should be sufficient, since it is equivalent to a P100 respirator, which is like N100 but also filters oil particles (according to my reading of [this website](http://www.coopersafety.com/respiratortypes.aspx) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N95)

Answer (score 4):

Try using a tile cutter instead.  A tile cutter is cheap, inexpensive and it cuts the board wet so there is nothing flying around to inhale.  Wear gloves too when handling the PCB's.  Tile cutters have a guide so you get a perfect straight line every time.

Comment: A tile cutter or a tile saw?

Answer (score 0):

A paper cutter cuts PCB dry without any dust. I have a flimsy plastic-y dull-bladed second-hand paper guillotine and even that, although not perfect, is much nicer than a Dremel that I have also tried. A sturdier cutter where the blade does not flex is better. A laminate cutter might work even better.